# How do I make my out-of-date code automatically built before being run?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, automation

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

When I change the code in my source file, then click the "Run" button on the debug tool-bar, Visual Studio does not automatically build the code, instead it runs the most recent manually built binaries.

[image]

I want to run my code just by simply clicking the "Run" button in the tool-bar; I don't want to press the "Build" button every time I want to run it, it becomes so annoying after a while. Currently, Visual Studio requires me to press the "Build" button before pressing the "Run" button. If I don't, it doesn't update my newest code changes in the exe file.

[image]

I opened the "Options" window above from `Menu Bar > Debug > Options and Settings...`.
And, as you see in my settings, I told Visual Studio to always build my projects if they are out of date; but it doesn't listen to me.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Does right-clicking the project/solution and selecting "clean" then running fix the problem? You may also look in to project build order.  Finally, it may be trivial, but you're pointing to "start debugging" not "run".

Comment: Works for me. You are probably changing a file which either isn't in your project or is a header that isn't included anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select your project and set it as startup project: "Project" -->
   "Set as StartUp Project"
2. Check if your project is set at the configuration manager: "Build"
   -->"Configuration Manager"

Comment: Yeah, the problem was related to "Configuration Manager". Newly added projects are not set to be built automatically. I was about to answer my own question, and saw your answer. Thank you. (Screen shot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CqPOU.png)